# Strange behaviour for setuid and setgid

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid

I am doing a small experiment with special privilege bits as follows:

```
[root@localhost~]# useradd user1
[root@localhost~]# cp /bin/touch /home/
[root@localhost~]# chown user1:user1 /home/touch
[root@localhost~]# chmod u+s,g+s /home/touch
[root@localhost~]# ls -l /home/touch
-rwsr-sr-x 1 user1 user1 52656 Jun 26 14:17 /home/touch
[root@localhost~]# chmod o+w /usr/local/etc/
[root@localhost~]# ls -ld /usr/local/etc
drwxr-xrwx.2 root root 4096 Jun 26 14:14 /usr/local/etc/
[root@localhost~]# /home/touch /usr/local/etc/root.1
/home/touch: cannot touch '/usr/local/etc/root.1': Permission denied
```

Because both suid bit and sgid bit are set for the executable `/home/touch`, I expected that when root executes the command `/home/touch /usr/local/etc/root.1`, the effective `user:group` should be `user1:user1`, which should have the write access to `/usr/local/etc` directory (see `o=rwx`).

But the result made me puzzled. Actually, anyone belonging to the `root` group will fail like root, but other users can run the above command successfully.

Only after I changed the directory mode by `chmod g+w /usr/local/etc`, can users belonging to the `root` group run the command without permission error.

Should not the effective user:group for anyone running `/home/touch` be `user1:user1`? What's wrong with the root group? Did I miss anything?

I took the experiment on RHEL 6.4 64-bit

Comment: I notice that the permissions output for `/usr/local/etc` (“`drwxr-xrwx.`”) ends with a period. This could mean that the directory has an ACL. Can you check on that?

Comment: Well, a directory or file with ACL is ended with "+" sign instead of ".".

Comment: I looked into the 'ls' documentation. It said: GNU 'ls' uses a '.' to indicate a file with an SELinux security context. In my environment, the SELinux feature is just disabled.